# Can't get label to initialize with a value

Tags: ios

Simple label on an iOS storyboard. I want to initialize its value to 0 when the app loads. In viewDidLoad, I have the following code:

```
NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
NSLog(@"%@", [val stringValue]);
self._model_rot_x_val.text = [val stringValue];
```

I can see in the console output that val has the correct value of 0. However, my label does not update. Do I need an outlet here or something here?

I have this in my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *_model_rot_x_val;
```

And I have this in the same .m file:

```
@synthesize _model_rot_x_val;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set labels value as 0 directly in viewDidLoad

```
self._model_rot_x_val.text = @"0";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the UILabel in Storyboard is connected to your `IBOutlet`. It is not enough to have an IBOutlet in your .h/.m files, you also need to connect it to the actual label in Storyboard.

Go to the bindings pane of the label in the Storyboard editor and check if the binding is there.

If the binding is not there, then ctrl-drag from the label to the controller where you have defined the `IBOutlet` and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you just initialise the value in the storyboard itself, or am I missing something?

Comment: In this example, yes. I have other situations where I need would prefer to initialize from values drawn from constants so that I can test with different starting points. That's why I was asking.